# How does sound melt concrete?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, acoustics

The sound power level (SPL) of the Saturn V rocket engines were 220 db.  There are numerous websites that state this is loud enough to melt concrete. An example from the website makeitlouder.com

220 (N)SATURN 5 ROCKETSHIP, MELTS CONCRETE AND BURNS GRASS ONE MILE AWAY

Comment: 220 db (SPL) is way too loud.

Comment: There was not only sound, but also a jet of hot gas.

Comment: Can you explain why you would believe anything written on makeitlouder.com?  It does not strike me as a good source for scientifically accurate information, so assuming that it is accurate seems like a poor assumption.

Comment: It should be hard to distinguish between sound and a hot jet

Comment: That SPL would be close to the one generated by a grenade. It would generate an overpressure of $10^6$ Pa.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea whether these websites are accurate. If the concrete is really melting because of the sound, it is because sound waves carry energy. Microscopically, the wave consists of moving air molecules. They’re not all moving in the same direction, but there is an overall longitudinal oscillation on top of the random motion. When the air molecules reflect from the concrete, they transfer additional kinetic energy from the oscillating motion to it and heat it up, beyond what their normal random motion does.